# using ffplay with Hstack command, how can I use -ss for each video

Tags: ffmpeg

How can I use ffplay  to use Hstack with -ss for each video

I tried this 1st with ffmpeg but I couldn't get it work with -ss on each video (like 10 seconds on 1st and 30 seconds on the 2nd)

thanx

Answer (score 0):

found how to do it

Batch File:

cd /d "C:\Desktop\ffplayHstack"

FFPLAY.EXE  -f lavfi "movie=Left.mkv:seek_point=20.2, scale=704:-1, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v0];movie=Right.mkv:seek_point=6.2, scale=704:-1, setpts=PTS-STARTPTS[v1];[v0][v1]hstack"